# i am making a function for image uploading in OOPs concept of php when i work on bind_param i dont know for image s or i

Tags: php, mysql, oop, bind

i am making a function for image uploading in OOPs concept of php  when i work on bind_param i dont know for image  s or i  main problem is in bind param tag this code is not full i show only my problem please help me ...

```
include('include/connect.php');
            $imgData=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES[][]);
            $imageProperties=getimagesize($_FILES[][]);

        $res=INSERT into user 
        }
    }




function addStudent($username,$password,$imageSize,$imageData)
    {
        $addS=$this->conn->prepare('');
        $addS->bind_param();
        $addS->execute();

        }
```

real problem is here

```
$addS->bind_param();
```

'ssss' or 'ssii'

Comment: It's recommended that you store only the path to the file in the database, I think.

Comment: will you give me link how can i store using path..

Comment: `<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_POST["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_POST["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_POST["files"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>`

Comment: In the previous code it takes the uploaded File from the POST and move it to the uploads folder. Then you need to take that path variable and insert it into your database.

Comment: |_thanks_ brother i'll apply on it.but it makes database heavy.

Comment: It's a lot lighter than storing blobs :)

Answer (score 0):

It deppend of the values that you want to bind:

```
                  Type specification chars
Character   Description
  i     corresponding variable has type integer
  d     corresponding variable has type double
  s     corresponding variable has type string
  b     corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

if $imageSize and $imageData are strings: 'ssss'

if $imageSize and $imageData are integers: 'ssii'

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: No problem. If you question is solved please select an answer.

Comment: i select but i not such reputations sir...so i apolize for that

Comment: Thank you. Do not worry about.